# Multiple independent JDialogs - setAlwaysOnTop affects all dialogs

Tags: java, jdialog

I'm creating multiple modeless JDialogs with 2 buttons. One to duplicate window and other to pin it to the screen (make it always on top). But it doesn't work like I expected. When I pin them to screen It works well. Window with alwaysOnTop set to true is always on top and others not. The problem is when I toggle alwaysOnTop to false on one of them. I expected to all others with alwaysOnTop set to true stay on top and that one not. But they are all behave like they have alwaysOnTop set on false;

The simple code to show my problem:

```java
public class Test extends JDialog{
     public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{
          SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(()->{new Test();});
     }

     private JToggleButton pinToScreenButton;
     private JButton cloneFrameButton;

     public Test(){
        this.setSize(200,200);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        pinToScreenButton = new JToggleButton("pin to screen");
        pinToScreenButton.addItemListener(e->{
        pinToScreenButtonAction(e);
      });
        add(pinToScreenButton);

        cloneFrameButton = new JButton("clone");
        cloneFrameButton.addActionListener(e->{
                cloneFrameButtonAction(this);}
        );
        add(cloneFrameButton);
        setVisible(true);
     }

        public void pinToScreenButtonAction(ItemEvent evt){
            if(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            }else{
                this.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            }
        }

    public void cloneFrameButtonAction(JDialog invoker){
            JDialog newDialog = new Test();
            newDialog.setLocation(invoker.getX()+10, invoker.getY()+15);
    }
}
```